# Storing a Query In A Variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been looking into storing a query into a variable but I am having trouble doing so. I keep getting the error

> wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'

This is what I tried

```
DECLARE
addresses VARCHAR(200);

 CURSOR allAddresses IS
      SELECT * 
      FROM ALL_ADDRESS;
BEGIN
 FOR rec IN allAddresses LOOP
      addresses := addresses || rec;  
 END LOOP;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(addresses);
END;
```

Comment: `rec` is of record data type. Use dot notation to access specific fields(columns) of the `rec` record, e.g. `rec.col_name`

Comment: You want to store the query text, or its results?

Comment: I wanted to store the results but the solution has already been given a couple of times here, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You refer to the columns in the record `rec` that you are using by name:

```
DECLARE
  addresses VARCHAR(200);

  CURSOR allAddresses IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM ALL_ADDRESS;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN allAddresses LOOP
    addresses := addresses || rec.house_number
                           || ' ' || rec.house_name
                           || ' ' || rec.address1
                           || ' ' || rec.address2;  
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(addresses);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `CURSOR for loop` iterator directly in your expressions.You can only refer to the  column names as `rec.col1` , `rec.col2` ..etc

```
DECLARE
addresses VARCHAR(200);

 CURSOR allAddresses IS
      SELECT * 
      FROM ALL_ADDRESS;
BEGIN
 FOR rec IN allAddresses LOOP
      addresses := addresses || rec.<address_column>;  
 END LOOP;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(addresses);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario you should understand cursor variable calling things:

```
DECLARE
  addresses VARCHAR(200);

  CURSOR allAddresses IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM ALL_ADDRESS;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN allAddresses LOOP
    addresses := addresses || rec.a;   -- A as attribute of your cursor
--- so your need to access your cursor attribute using loop name i.e rec
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(addresses);
    END;
    /
```

whenever you are trying to access your cursor record, you should call cursor variable before the attribute.
Hope it will help you.. thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
addresses := addresses || '' || rec;
```